# IDE Error when creating a new activity in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problems to create new activities in Android Studios 3.0.1 for Windows 10, the issue is that until yesterday everything worked, but now it throws errors when trying to create a new activity and then, do not create it.

Only create classes, or empty activities, but no other that appears in the gallery.

The error message is:

> Inconsistent FILE tree in SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=LightVirtualFile: \targetFile, content=VirtualFileContent{size=69}}; nodeLength=137; fileLength=69

[image: First Error Window]

[image: Second Error Window]

I've done everything, I've downloaded the latest version of gradle and I've reinstalled Android Studio, several times.

Comment: I'm facing this issue on MacOS High Sierra also

Comment: Will it be a recent update ?, the truth is a problem, it stops the current development of the apps

Comment: It happens also in Linux. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 64-bits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It's a known bug**: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22349

Problem: Create new Activity in Android Studio from Gallery

Android Studio: Android Studio 3.0.1. (MacOS and Windows)

Recent Update: I had recently updated to the newest update of Kotlin plugin `Version: 1.2.20-release-Studio3.0-1`.

Solution that worked for me: I turned off Kotlin plugin in Android Studio -> Plugins -> Kotlin and restarted Android Studio. The problem was gone.

On turning on Koltin plugin again the problem came back as well.

**Update:** The issue is resolved in the latest update `v-1.2.21` - If you don't see it in Android Studio under plugins then download directly from the website: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Comment: you are amazing, the problem was the last update of kotlin, the issue is that I can not turn it off or stop working apps that have kotlin, so what I did was a downgrade from this to the previous version and solved the problem. Thanks again

Comment: Worked like a charm :D Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT (27/01/2018)** : The issue have been fixed by Jetbrains. Just update your Kotlin plugin.

---

As @Sharj said, it is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22349).

The first solution is to disable the Kotlin plugin : **Files** > **Settings** > **Plugins** and unckeck **Kotlin**.

--

But if you need to use the plugin, you have to downgrade it to version **1.2.10**.

To do so download the **1.2.10** plugin archive on the [Jetbrain Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin) corresponding to your Android Studio version. For me it is **1.2.10-release-Studio3.0-1**.

Then install it : **Files** > **Settings** > **Plugins** and select <kbd>Install plugin from disk...</kbd>. Choose your `1.2.10-release-Studio3.0-1.zip` archive you just downloaded and then restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the plugin (1.2.21-release-Studio3.01-1) resolved the issue.

Comment: looks like it's `1.2.21-release-Studio3.0-1` or `1.2.21-release-Studio3.1-1` going from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin